# How can i extract the name of the directory a given `.torrent` would create from the underlying bencode data?

Tags: python, bittorrent, torrent

What is the simplest way to parse bencode in python to get the directory name that a `.torrent` file produces?

`.torrent` files names and the directory names they produce are rarely if ever the same. I am working on an app that hands over a `.torrent` file to a server and to retrieve it when it has completed. I need to know the name of the file the `.torrent` file creates without actually initiating the download. I cannot perform any operations server-side.

previously I achieved this with the rather bulky dependency of a full torrent client (libtorrent). This is no longer feasible. I am sadly not smart enough to understand how libtorrent solves this, but the command to get the filename is:

```
import libtorrent as lt

TORRENT = <direntry item that is a .torrent file>


def getFileNamefromTorrent(torrent):
    """must be a direntry item. Gets the name of the torrent's finished folder from the .torrent file."""
    torrent_info = lt.torrent_info(torrent.path)
    return torrent_info.name()

print(getFileNameFromTorrent(TORRENT)
```

My first attempts have been parsing the bencode, where i can get the file names :

```
import bencode
import itertools

TORRENT = "path to .torrent file"

def getTorrentFilenames(filename):
    with open(filename, "rb") as fin:
        torrent = bencode.bdecode(fin.read())
        
    return itertools.chain(*(f["path"] for f in torrent["info"]["files"]))

for file in getTorrentFilenames(TORRENT)
```

this gives me the files that are inside the torrent, but does **not** provide the name of the directory it puts them in.

i tried access different elements in the dict(like `name` instead of `files` but that produce a `typeError`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "torrent_management.py", line 65, in <module>
    test = listTorrent(TESTTORRENT)
  File "torrent_management.py", line 63, in listTorrent
    return itertools.chain(*(f["path"] for f in torrent["info"]["name"]))
  File "torrent_management.py", line 63, in <genexpr>
    return itertools.chain(*(f["path"] for f in torrent["info"]["name"]))
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I apologize if I am overlooking something very obvious. The [BitTorrent .torrent metainfo file structure](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Metainfo_File_Structure) mentions there is a "name" in the dictionary.

I have provided a minimum working example in the above code section that runs in python. the dictonary should provide the name of the torrent encoded in bencode, but it is not a valid dict item.

Answer (score 0):

I found out where I was going wrong.

the correct, minimal solution is as follows:
(if you are having problems with using the bencode library, make sure you use `bencode.py` and not `bencode` .

```
import bencode

def getTorrentName(filename):
    """List name of a torrent from the corresponding .torrent file."""
    with open(filename, "rb") as fin:
        torrent = bencode.bdecode(fin.read())
    
    return torrent["info"]["name"]

torrent = <location of .torrent>

torrentName = getTorrentName(torrent)
```

Also, apparently the "name" key is strictly advisory. I am not sure if the "name" key is used to produce the corresponding directory or it just correlates with it. would love to know!

Comment: Correct, the 'name' field is the directory the torrent will be placed in.  In [some cases](https://pastebin.com/4WL1bfib) a torrent will only have a 'name' field, and no list of files.  For such torrents, generally torrent clients will place the single file of the torrent in the download directory named after the name field.  If the name field is not present or broken, most torrent clients fall back to using the infohash as the directory name.

Comment: Note that [BEP52](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0052.html#file-tree-layout) uses a different layout and clients may or may not use the display name for directory structures.